# Apache Ignite 2.1 not start

Tags: java, ignite

I just tried the latest version of Apache Ignite (2.1) with a very basic configuration, and it doesn't work.

This line below doen't work (works until 2.0.0) :

```
Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(new IgniteConfiguration());
```

Does someone know what I am doing wrong? I know that it's a too basic configuration, I have the same result when using an example config file.

The stack below :

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.registerCache(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/ignite/internal/processors/cache/GridCacheContext;Lorg/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration;)V
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.registerCache0(GridQueryProcessor.java:1276)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.onCacheStart0(GridQueryProcessor.java:756)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.onCacheStart(GridQueryProcessor.java:817)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.startCache(GridCacheProcessor.java:1265)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.onKernalStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:898)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1013)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1895)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1647)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1075)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:595)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:519)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:322)
    at com.test.Test.go(Test.java:9)
    at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:15)

[16:29:10] Cancelled rebalancing from all nodes [topology=null]
juil. 31, 2017 4:29:10 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
GRAVE: Failed to stop component (ignoring): GridProcessorAdapter []
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheSharedContext.database()Lorg/apache/ignite/internal/processors/cache/persistence/IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager;
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.stop(IgniteH2Indexing.java:2067)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.stop(GridQueryProcessor.java:269)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.stop0(IgniteKernal.java:2180)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.stop(IgniteKernal.java:2047)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1052)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1895)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1647)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1075)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:595)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:519)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:322)
    at com.test.Test.go(Test.java:9)
    at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:15)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheSharedContext.database()Lorg/apache/ignite/internal/processors/cache/persistence/IgniteCacheDatabaseSharedManager;
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.stop(IgniteH2Indexing.java:2067)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.stop(GridQueryProcessor.java:269)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.stop0(IgniteKernal.java:2180)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.stop(IgniteKernal.java:2047)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1052)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1895)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1647)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1075)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:595)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:519)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:322)
    at com.test.Test.go(Test.java:9)
    at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you updated version for all artifacts (ignite-indexing, ignite-core and etc)?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply. Yes, I update all Ignite dependencies (ignite-core and ignite-indexing) to "2.1.0". I also think about dependency problem, but I tried with only these 2 dependencies and it still not work. It is surely something stupid because I don't see why it would not work only on my side...

Comment: Hmm... Could you share output for 'mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose', If you use maven?

Comment: OK, I just re-created a project with just the test class and purge my ".m2" repository and it works now. Sorry for the waste of time and thank you for time you spent on my problem.

Comment: It's great news! No problem )